# How to save a web resource, applying decoding to URL Encoded Characters?

Tags: filenames, curl, wget, url

I would like to save this file with this URL "http://pti.regione.sicilia.it/portal/page/portal/PIR_PORTALE/PIR_LaStrutturaRegionale/PIR_AssessoratoEconomia/PIR_DipBilancioTesoro/PIR_Areetematiche/PIR_ServizioStatistica/PIR_1839271.4501140784/PIR_idatidellaSicilia/spesa%20del%20settore%20sanit%E0.csv" using its source name, but saving it applying decoding to URL Encoded Characters it has.

The name we have in the URL is `spesa%20del%20settore%20sanit%E0.csv`, I would like to programmatically convert it in `spesa del settore sanità.csv`. In the source name we have `%20` that is a space and `%E0` that is `à`.

How to do this name conversion?

I could create a search and replace list starting from this [table](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) but I imagine there is an utility, a library that could do it for me.
However I do not find a proper way to do it using simply wget or curl.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Wget is built with IRI support, then it will handle this case automatically.

Take a look at your `wget --version`. Mine shows this:

```
GNU Wget 1.20.1.7-5dce-dirty built on linux-gnu.

-cares +digest +gpgme +https +ipv6 +iri +large-file +metalink +nls 
+ntlm +opie +psl +ssl/gnutls
```

The important part for you here is the `+iri`. Most distributions should compile it with IRI enabled by default.

EDIT: 
It seems like the server in this case sends the filename encoded in latin-1. While the default assumption is always utf-8. Ideally, the server should send a `Content-Disposition` header to mention this. It can however be handled by Wget is you pass the `--remote-encoding=latin1` option to it.

Comment: Hi darnir I have `-cares +digest -gpgme +https +ipv6 +iri +large-file -metalink +nls
+ntlm +opie +psl +ssl/gnutls`, than I should have +iri support. But if I run wget myURL I have `‘spesa del settore sanit\340.csv’ saved [859/859]` and not `‘spesa del settore sanità.csv’ saved [859/859]`

Comment: Aah yes.. As user @JdeBP mentioned, the name is not correct UTF-8, which causes this problem. And the server doesn't send a header telling the client that it should interpret it as latin-1 instead.

Comment: Hi darnir, but how to read the reply header of the server? If I run `curl  HEAD -I myURL`, I have no info back encoding related.
Thank you

Comment: You don't need to. With Wget you can use `-S` to print the server reply, but as mentioned in my answer, Wget would deal with it automatically if the Content-Disposition header was mentioned with the name and encoding.

Answer (score 2):

More generally than just `wget`:

The `unvis` tool does this, with the `-h` option to specify percent encoding.  (The OpenBSD and MacOS versions of the tool do not have this, note.)

Your percent-encoded name is not in UTF-8, notice.

```
% printf '%s' 'spesa%20del%20settore%20sanit%E0.csv' | unvis -h | hexdump -C
00000000  73 70 65 73 61 20 64 65  6c 20 73 65 74 74 6f 72  |spesa del settor|
00000010  65 20 73 61 6e 69 74 e0  2e 63 73 76              |e sanit..csv|
0000001c
% printf '%s\n' 'spesa%20del%20settore%20sanit%E0.csv' | unvis -h | iconv -f latin1
spesa del settore sanità.csv
%
```

## Further reading

- [`unvis`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=unvis&sektion=1).  *FreeBSD   General Commands Manual*.  2010-11-27.
- [`unvis`](http://man.openbsd.org/unvis.1). *OpenBSD General Commands Manual*. 2013-08-12.

Comment: Thank you very much @JdeBP. I do not find a way to install unvis. It's not possible in my debian with apt-get.